# How to normalize a two-particle state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, normalization

Say I have a state of two non-interacting fermions in some system,
$$\Psi_{12}(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\Psi_1(x_1)\Psi_2(x_2)+\Psi_1(x_2)\Psi_2(x_1))\otimes\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\uparrow\downarrow-\downarrow\uparrow)$$
where $\Psi_i$s are stationary states of one particle systems. My question is how do I normalize this? I know how to set these states up but I'm not sure how to get the normalization constants.
For example, can you move that second fraction up to the front? Or do I normalize separately? In that case, everything is already normalized.

Comment: Assuming $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ are normalized, then the state is already normalized.

Comment: @MengCheng So the idea is if this state is not normalized i should just go back and normalize the single particle states? Is there a way to normalize the state if I am just presented with some state like this and don't know the original form of $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's just ignore the spin part because it's trivial to normalize that part. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\int dx_1 \int dx_2 |\Psi_{12}(x_1, x_2)|^2 &=& \frac{1}{2} \int dx_1 \int dx_2 |\Psi_1(x_1) \Psi_2(x_2) + \Psi_1(x_2) \Psi_1(x_2)|^2 \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \Big[\int d x_1 |\Psi_1(x_1)|^2 \int d x_2 |\Psi_2(x_2)|^2 \\
&& + \int dx_1 |\Psi_2(x_1)|^2\int dx_2 |\Psi_1(x_2)|^2 \\
&& + \int dx_1  \left(\Psi_1^\star(x_1) \Psi_2(x_1) + c.c. \right) \int dx_2  \left(\Psi_1^\star(x_2) \Psi_2(x_2) + c.c. \right) \Big]
\end{eqnarray}
If the 1-particle states are normalized such that
\begin{equation}
\int dx \Psi^\star_i (x) \Psi_j(x)= \delta_{ij}
\end{equation}
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta symbol (it is $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise), then
\begin{equation}
\int dx_1 \int dx_2 |\Psi_{12}(x_1, x_2)|^2 = 1
\end{equation}